# I cannot remove authentication to access phpMyAdmin

Tags: 14.04, phpmyadmin

Hie, I forgot my authentication user name and password to login to my phpMyAdmin. I did not create or wanted to have authentication page to access my database through phpMyAdmin.

I have lost the database name and hosting IP. I want to disable the authentication to the PHPMyadmin site using my_domain.com/phpMyadmin.

I tried all sorts of things like changing the MySql root user password. Created new users but i cannot get around it.

Plase help

Comment: Additionally i have: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true; $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';On config.inc.php –  in the config.inc.php file the authetication shows $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config'; However, I tried it with HTTP and cookies too but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Reset your MySQL root password by doing the following:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

then start mysql skipping table granting

```
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

Login to MySQL as root

```
mysql -u root mysql
```

Change your root password

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('new-password') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
```

Restart mysql

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Try your new  login to phpmyadmin as root with your new password

Comment: Doesnot work. Additionally i have:
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;                                        
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';                                                                                     
On config.inc.php

Comment: Please add all of these comments to your question above

Answer (score 0):

You have several methods:

1. Use the mysql's root user to log in, and change the password of the user after that.
2. Contact the hosting company to reset/change the password for you.
3. Ask a professional to help you.

Comment: I created my own hosting on a clean server. I am using webmin to control all my connections. therefore, i installed PhpMyadmin in UBUNTU server.

Comment: I tried using username: root and its password but it wont work.mydomain:port 80 gives 401 Unathourized error.

Comment: Log in on SSH and use mysqladmin, or better ask someone who knows what is doing. (This is why I hate  all kind of server manipulation gui systems... :( )

Comment: What kind of login is using the PHPMyAdmin? Perhaps you have set a .htpasswd based auth?

Comment: Please add all of these comments to your question above

Comment: @Frantique.. in the config.inc.php file the authetication shows $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';  However, I tried it with HTTP and cookies too but no luck